# Undefined stdClass::render() Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple pagination code and when I try to run it I get the error `Call to undefined method stdClass::render()`. Here are my codes:

**Controller**:

```
public function showNews()
    {
        $news = DB::table('tcity_news')->paginate(1);
        return view('newspage', ['news' => $news]);
    }
```

**Route**:

```
Route::get('/newsroom/city-news', 'TugsiteController@showNews');
```

**Blade**:

```
@foreach ($news as $news)
{{$news->newsTitle}}
@endforeach

{!! $news->render() !!}
```

The render() method is undefined, but I am running the latest version of Laravel. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure you're not breaking things with `@foreach ($news as $news)` having the same name?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Got it, thanks. I can vote you as best answer if you will post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `@foreach ($news as $news)` you are basically changing the definition of `$news` so that it won't be what you expect in the `render()` part. This is why the function is not found.

Answer (score 1):

`@foreach ($news as $news)` for this line laravel is getting your news object which you already converted into loop try to use some different name . Like

```
@foreach ($news as $new)
```

and then `{!! $news !!} or {!! $news->render() !!}`. Now laravel will able to differentiate between the data rendered to your view and data you are converting into loop as object .

hope that will bring joy .